# PDE with terminal condition, Feynman-Kac

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have the following PDE:
$$2u_t+9u_{xx}-2u_x=0$$
$$u(x,T)=e^x$$
and I get that
$$dX(s)=-dS+3dW(s)$$
$$X(t)=x$$

But how do I get the expected value of $e^x$?
I tried substituting $Y(s)=e^x$, but I get the wrong answer... The answer should be $u(x,t)=e^{(x+\frac{7}{2}(T-t))}$.

Comment: What is $X, S, W$ ?

Comment: Sorry, X is a stochastic process, W is a Wiener process and S is time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Your SDE results in the following expression:

$X(T) = x  - (T - t) + 3(W(T) - W(t))$

Now you just need to find $E[e^{X(T)}]$
Can you do that?

Hint2: MGF